# Recreating Openstreetmap on your Mysql PHP - Server

Tags: php, mysql, openstreetmap

I want to recreate something like this;

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-71.31,42.251,-70.883,42.482&amp;layer=mapnik&amp;marker=42.36652,-71.09620" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=42.3665&amp;lon=-71.0965&amp;zoom=11&amp;layers=M&amp;mlat=42.36652&amp;mlon=-71.09620">Gr&amp;#246;&amp;#223;ere Karte anzeigen</a></small>
```

So I have a system with unix, php and mysql. You can download osm files with maps. But how do you have an 'applet' in which you can move and scroll the content, while all data is on my server so fast speed and no rate limits and what is more: availability when the server is available.

I found answers using perl and PostgreSQL but I don't have PostgreSQL and the perl-scripts need more files I cannot install as it is a shared server.

How do I do it with my system to have the nice "applet" there while all data comes from my "own" server?

Comment: If you want to load the OSM data into a database you will have to use PostgreSQL. AFAIK MySQL's (geo)spatial features are too limited to be used by OSM (at least that's what I have heard)

Comment: is it as performant as creating tiles for all parts that I want and to just cut out the ones whose areas are being requested. Is it easy to geocode those image files so on another layer there will be poi?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set up your own [tile server](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/). First, make sure your system meets the requirements described on that page. Then choose one of the three possibilities. The first one describing how to build a [tile server from packages](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/) is probably the easiest one.

Regarding your comment: POIs will be automatically on those tiles. If you want them on an extra layer, you have to modify the [stylesheet](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik#Stylesheet) of [Mapnik](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik) and remove all POIs from it and then create a separate POI layer using [OpenLayers](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-openlayers/) or [Leaflet](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet/).